# call script after element is fully visible

Tags: jquery, mcustomscrollbar

I'm using this script below for loading a hidden div, inside another:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function() {
        $('#menu a').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#menu a').removeClass("selected");
            $(this).addClass("selected");
            var h = $(this).attr('href');
            $("#conteudo").fadeOut("slow", function() {
                $(this).html($(h).html()).fadeIn("slow");
            });
        });
 });
```

But in some pages, I use some [mCustomScrollbar](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller), which only works if the div is not hidden. So I need to call the script after the div is fully visible. How I can do that with the code above?

This is the scrollBar script call:

```
$("#mcs_container").mCustomScrollbar("vertical",400,"easeOutCirc",1.05,"auto","yes","yes",10);
```

In the page of script, it has this example code, but my script load is valid for the entire menu ... and this example it is setting what page he wants to carry. Do I make myself clear?

```
$("#mcs_container .content").load("new.html", function(){
    $("#mcs_container").mCustomScrollbar("vertical",400,"easeOutCirc",1.05,"auto","yes","yes",10);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a callback function to the `.fadeIn()` function that will be executed once the animation has ended (making the `<div>` visible). It should look something like this:

```
$("#conteudo").fadeOut("slow", function() {
    $(this).html($(h).html()).fadeIn("slow", function() {
        $("#mcs_container").mCustomScrollbar("vertical",400,"easeOutCirc",1.05,"auto","yes","yes",10);
    });
});
```

Comment: great! As I have not thought of that before? And if i want to call the Scrollbar only in some `div`, i can make a `if` condition... right?